# DbUpdateException was Unhandled by user code in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, chat, dbcontext

I am working with chat server like [Jobbr.net](http://jobbr.net). when i close group chat tab then i am getting `DbUpdateException` was Unhandled by user code

**Code:**

```
public void CommitChanges()
{
 _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

[Click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKyma.png)

Comment: would you please write the whole code where you are calling CommitChanges() function.

Comment: A possibility is that you have an empty table in the database. Can you create the table in the Server Explorer, populate it with a row, and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you got a problem with your data model or the data you want to persist. I guess some required field or foreign key is not set when you try to save the entity.

Try catching and logging the `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException`. It should tell you which entity causes the problem. Here is some logging code that we use:

```
using NLog;

private static Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

try {
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException upEx) {

    if (upEx.Entries != null && upEx.Entries.Any()) {
        Logger.Debug("DbUpdateException contained '{0}' entries:", upEx.Entries.Count());

         // get info about the Entity that produced the error
         foreach (var dbEntityEntry in upEx.Entries) {
             if (dbEntityEntry.Entity != null) {
                 var entityType = dbEntityEntry.Entity.GetType();
                 try {
                     var id = entityType.GetProperty("Id").GetValue(dbEntityEntry.Entity, null);
                     Logger.Debug("DbUpdateException contains DbEntityEntry - Type: '{0}', Id: '{1}', State: '{2}'", entityType.Name, id, dbEntityEntry.State.ToString("G"));
                 } catch (Exception) {
                     Logger.Debug("DbUpdateException contains DbEntityEntry - Type '{0}', Id: unknown, State: '{2}'", entityType.Name, dbEntityEntry.State.ToString("G"));
                 }
             }
         }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hello @Georg, this catch block will automatically solved foreign key problem or not ?? if not, then what changes i have to do ??

Comment: The code block given above will just let you collect more information about your error. If an exception occurs, the error will be logged and nothing will be persisted. A Foreign Key Exception points to a problem with the data you want to persist - a relationship that is required by your data model has not been set on the entity you are trying to save. You have to check the method that calls `CommitChanges()`and check whether everything is set correctly on the entities that shall be updated.

Comment: I hope I did point you in the right direction. Good luck fixing your bug :>